# Android fragment with image unresponsive on close

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, bitmap

I have an activity with two fragments, one a list of images and second a View image fragment, which should be opened when an image is clicked.
For the listview, I used an asynctask as per the developer's documentation to load the images in background and it is working with good responsiveness. BTW, the images are loading are all from the SDcard, and are not downloaded.

Here is my code in onCreateView in the details fragment.

```
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_image, container, false);
    Log.d("ViewImage",mFilePath);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.viewImage1);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFilePath);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Button CloseButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.viewImageCloseButton);
    CloseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.closeViewImage();
        }
    });
```

Its working correctly. Screenshot of the fragment below. 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nka9i.jpg)

The closeViewImage() method called from the activity is

```
    public void closeViewImage(){
    if(mViewImageFragment != null){
        mCamFragment = CamFragment.newInstance(" "," ");
        getSupportFragmentManager().
                beginTransaction().
                replace(R.id.container,mCamFragment,"CAM").
                commit();
        mViewImageFragment = null;
    }

}
```

The issue I am facing is, when installed on devices with actual snaps, clicking on the Close button as we see in the snapshots, the click is very unresponsive.  Its not exactly throwing an ANR, but sort of like it takes 2-3 seconds to close the fragment.

Can anyone look at the code and comment what I am doing wrong ?

Note:
The fragment is loading fast enough when I click on the image from the list view.  I know processing bitmaps off the UI thread is required and will do that, but what exactly must be done to while closing a fragment with an image from a bitmap ?

Comment: I can't see all of your code - but are you creating a new instance of CamFragment when you are closing?  If so, you should instead "find" the fragment and replace it with CAM - not create a new instance.  Let me know and I can post some code to do it if you want